# How to programmatically set corner radius of MenuItem border

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I access the border of a MenuItem in order to change the Corner Radius?

This is not working:

```
Style menuitemStyle = new Style(typeof(MenuItem));
menuitemStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = Border.CornerRadiusProperty, Value = 2 });
m.Style = menuitemStyle;
```

Here is the xaml (there is nothing to it):

```
<Grid><StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="spSub" VerticalAlignment="Top"  >
            </StackPanel></Grid
```

> > > Update<<<
> > >       I tried adding this to the xaml but the MenuItem border is still square:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="subMenuItem" TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Border CornerRadius="5"></Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Does this need to be done in code? If you use XAML to declare this style in the application resources it will automatically be used by all menu items.

Comment: I build the menu programmatically and add it to a stackpanel.  The reason I do this is to be able to change the orientation from horizontal to vertical programmatically.

Comment: There is no CornerRadius property for a menu item. Can you share your XAML ?

Comment: I just added the xaml - it's not much.  I did know that there is no CornerRadius on a MenuItem.  Was wondering if there was a way to access the Border style on a MenuItem to add CornerRadius

Comment: I think you need to overwrite the control template of the Menuitem if you want to achieve Rounded border for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a style in XAML and overwrite the control template.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                                        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="10" CornerRadius="10">
                                            <TextBlock Text="Content" ></TextBlock>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
</Style>
```

You should be able to modify the TextBlock to your desired display control or bind your data to it accordingly. I just exaggerated the BorderThickness to show how the changes would look.

Comment: This looks like a winner!  Thanks!